# Javascript Progress Bar Onclick Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, onclick, progress-bar

I don't understand why the button2 is not adding £5 on each click, and is instead multiplying it by 10 (after 3 clicks I get 0555). 
The button1 is adding £1 by £1 to the progress bar as it should thanks to count++, and I thought that the "+=5" would do the trick for button2.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone point me toward the solution?

```html
<body>
<div id="content" class="col-md-4">
    <h1>Donation<span class="label label-default" id="count">0</span></h1>
    <div class="progress">
        <div id="percent" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="button1" class="btn">£1</button>
    <button id="button2" class="btn">£5</button>
</div>
</body>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(addVisit);
    $("#button2").click(addVisitFive);
});

function addVisit(){
    var countTag = $('#count');
    var count = countTag.text();
    var progressTag = $('#percent');
    count ++;
    countTag.text(count);
    progressTag.css('width', count * 10 + "%");
}

function addVisitFive(){
    var countTag = $('#count');
    var count = countTag.text();
    var progressTag = $('#percent');
    count +=5;
    countTag.text(count);
    progressTag.css('width', count * 10 + "%");
}
```

Comment: Hi Allesandrod, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I added a little extra formatting to the code in your question, to make it more readable - it should help readers understand it and find an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `countTag.text();` is returning the string value and `count` is incremented by `count++` thanks to type coercion. `count += 5` however won't try to coerce the type and instead you get the default behavior when you use a string and the `+` operator which is concatenation, thus `0555` after 3 clicks.

Try: `+(countTag.text())` to use the unary `+` operator which will convert the string to a number in base 10. If it's not a number, you'll get `NaN` instead which is arguably more favorable behavior than trying to use `parseInt(countTag.text())`.

Comment: I tried your hint, unfortunately is still not behaving as it should